# Using trackBy on Angular mat-table with rows of editable formcontrols

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm using a mat-table component that contains a single default row that may have multiple formControls in each cell column. I'm using onPush changeDetectionStrategy for all of my components.

The user can edit any of the formControl control elements in this default row. For example, changing the value of a select that contains a list of US states.

I have an "Add Row" button that allows the user to create an empty copy of the first row. They can create as many rows as they like and fill in the data in each row (the resulting data is ultimately submitted as part of a reactive formControl).

I am using a trackBy function attached to the table element in order to prevent each row from redrawing when a new row is added (Assuming none of the formcontrols in the already rendered rows have changed their values since the last time addRow was called).

The issue I have is that, with the current trackBy setup, after 2 rows have been added, the first row is no longer mutable. The trackby apparently caches that row. I am not using recyclerows directive, only trackby.

Is this supposed to be doable or am I asking more of the angular mat-table than its capable of?

```
<table
  #table
  mat-table
  matSort
  matSortDisableClear
  [trackBy]="options.trackByEnable? trackByTest : null"
  >
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableConfig?.columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableConfig?.columns;"></tr>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of tableConfig?.columns; index as i;" matColumnDef="{{column}}">
      <td mat-cell
        [ngClass]="{'hidden-column': tableConfig?.hiddenColumns.includes(column)}"
        *matCellDef="let row; let rowIndex = index;">
        <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="!['builder'].includes(mode) && tableConfig?.columnTypes[column] === 'default'">{{ row[column] }}</ng-container> -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="column !== ACTIONS_COLUMN_NAME">
          <div *ngIf="layout[i] && layout[i].widget">
            <drag-drop-menu *ngIf="dragDropEnhancedMode" #menu class="no-display-inline no-display-tooltip" [item]="childTemplateModel[i]"></drag-drop-menu>
    <!-- THIS WIDGET LOADS MATERIAL INPUT FORMCONTROLS -->
            <select-widget-widget
              [class]="dragDropEnhancedMode && childTemplateModel ? getActiveItemClass(childTemplateModel[i]) : ''"
              (change)="onCellChange($event, rowIndex, column)"
              [logic]="layout[i]?.options?.logic || {}"
              [rowIndex]="rowIndex + paginationRowOffset"
              [dataIndex]="[].concat(rowIndex + paginationRowOffset)"
              [layoutIndex]="(layoutIndex || []).concat(i)"
              [layoutNode]="layout[i]">
            </select-widget-widget>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </td>

    </ng-container>
  </table>    


trackByTest(index: any, column: any): any {
  /* row data is in the form:
    {inputTest: '', hiddenTest: ''}
  */
  // console.log('hidden[inputTest]: ', column['inputTest']); // returns value of "inputTest" formControl
  // console.log('hidden[hiddenTest]: ', column['hiddenTest']); // returns value of "hiddenTest" formControl
  return column['hiddenTest'];
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `trackBy` in the `tr`? I don't know if using it in the `table` element is correct

Comment: @Andres2142, yes, it is allowable to use it in the TR. I've tried it but I still get similar behavior. Is the trackBy limited to Add/Remove rows or can it detect row changes within a previously indexed row?

Comment: For example, if I set the trackBy return to `return index`, and the row at that index initially is set to {hiddenTest: 'foo', inputTest: 'bar'} and after an edit it becomes mutated to {hiddenTest: 'bar', inputTest: 'foo'}, the trackBy should redraw the row or no? I need it to redraw the row. My current setup only redraws it if its >= the highest index - 1

Comment: A stackblitz may be helpful to diagnose your specific impl, if one is available. The trackBy function used by the mat-table is just the one from angular core, it requires a distinct value for each row returned when defining a custom function, so index would make sense at a minimum. A unique object ID would also make sense, but returning `column['hiddenTest']`, could it be possible that this value is not distinct for each row? Sounds like you tried index and it didn't solve your problem, but, returning `column['hiddenTest']` has me curious if the value will be distinct enough for the function.